# C++: Pass struct to PThread

Tags: c++, struct, pthreads

So I am trying to pass several values to a thread by using a struct.

This is what I have:

```
int main()
{

struct Data
{
int test_data;
int test_again;
};

Data data_struct;
data_struct.test_data = 0;
data_struct.test_again = 1;

pthread_create(&thread, NULL, Process_Data, (void *)&data_struct);
return 0;
}


void* Process_Data(void *data_struct)
{
 struct test
{
    int test_variable;
    int test_two;
};
test testing;
testing.test_variable = *((int *)data_struct.test_data);
testing.test_two = *((int *)data_struct.test_again);
}
```

I have left out any code (inluding `#include`s and thrad joins etc) I think is unnecessary for this question for the sake of simplicity, however if more code is needed please just ask.

The thread worked fine when passing just one integer variable.

This is the error I am getting:

In function 'void* Process_Data(void*): error: request for member 'test_variable' in 'data_struct' which is of a non-class type 'void*' testing.test_variable = *((int *)data_test.test_variable);

And the same for the other variable

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Well, the joins make some difference. Without them, what's keeping the struct alive?

Comment: Is [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) not an option for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usual way is

```
void* Process_Data(void *data_struct)
{
  Data *testing = static_cast<Data*>(data_struct);

  // testing->test_data and testing->test_again are
  // data_struct.test_data and data_struct.test_again from main
}
```

You get the error you get because you try to pick members from a `void` pointer, which does not have any. In order to use the struct you know the `void` pointer points to, you have to cast it back to a pointer to that struct.

Also, note that you should `pthread_join` the thread you just started, or main will end before it can do anything.

Comment: Thanks @Wintermute, the issue now is that `Data` is not declared in the scope of the thread, should I be somehow passing the actual structure instead of an instance of it (i.e. pass `Data` instead of `data_struct`)?

Comment: The structure itself is not an object (it's a type of object), so you cannot pass it to the function. I would declare the struct outside of main so both functions know it. In a header, if the functions are in different translation units.

Answer (score 1):

You have untyped void* pointer from which you're trying to extract data

Try first to cast pointer to something and then use it

```
Data* p = (Data*)data_struct;

int a = p->test_data;
int b = p->test_again;
```

Comment: C-style casts are bad mmkay.